# Can I use left-to-right style with `auto` for declaring a raw pointer?

Tags: c++, auto

While trying to follow [the left-to-right declaration style](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) I've came across the case of declaring a default-initialized raw pointer with `auto`, with no luck:

```
auto* ptr = T*{};           // Error
auto* ptr = (T*){};         // Error
auto* ptr = nullptr_t<T>{}; // (I was desperate enough) - Error
```

What is the right way of doing that? Or that's not possible at all?

Comment: `auto* ptr = static_cast<T*>(nullptr);` :-)

Comment: `template<class T> using raw_ptr = T*;` `auto p = raw_ptr<int>{};` perhaps? :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB, that's what I was looking for! Pretty cumbersome, though. I think that construct makes more advisable left-typing for this cases. If you posted this as an aswer I would mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't *have* to use `auto` for everything. It's very much a judgment call, and you should consider it just one more tool in the toolbox that should be used when it makes the code easier to read.

Typical uses of `auto` are when the initializing expression already contains the return type "obviously" enough:

```
auto it = v.begin();  // OK, some iterator, details unimportant
auto up = std::make_unique<T>(a, b, c);  // well-known maker function
auto * p = new T(a, b, c);  // must be a T *
auto * dp = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(bp);  // must be a Derived *
auto * p = const_cast<T *>(cp);  // must be a T *
```

In the same vein you could write:

```
auto * p = static_cast<T *>(nullptr);  // must be a T *
```

However, that's ultimately no improvement over the more direct:

```
T * p = nullptr;
```

Finally, compare these two:

```
auto * p = const_cast<T *>(cp);       // OK, p is a T *
const auto & cr = std::as_const(r);   // What is cr?
```

This demonstrates the fine line one has to walk here: The second line uses a type-deducing maker function, so all we know is that we end up with a constant reference, but the type remains hidden. It is very much a matter of care and discretion whether this is appropriate or too obscure. If your readers can't understand the code without performing non-local lookups, it's probably an `auto` too far.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why do you use `*` with `auto`? This should work fine:

```
auto ptr = (T*){};
```

Comment: Using * is just a style preference. I think using it makes easier understanding the code later.